# как убрать эту белую линию в vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

как убрать эту белую линию в vs code?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Настройки>Editor:render line highlight (поставить на none) это выключит подсветку